# How to add an extra static cell to my UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an array of photos that I currently display in a `UICollectionView`. The only thing I still want to add is an extra static cell that should give the user the possibility to open the camera. I used an `if-else` statement to detect the index. Unfortunately, the console gives me an out of index error.

To be precise: I want this static cell to be in the top left corner, followed by my array of images. Do I have to add two sections, or should I register another custom cell to accomplish this? As of now I can see my extra cell, but it's not working when tapped (out of index).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoId, for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.row == imageArray.count {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedCamera)))
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedPhoto)))
    }

    return cell
}
```

**Updated code (solution)**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cameraCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cameraId, for: indexPath) as! CameraCollectionViewCell
        return cameraCell
    }

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedPhoto))
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoId, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row - 1]
    cell.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print("Camera")
    } 
}

var startingFrame: CGRect?
var blackBackGroundView: UIView?
var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
var selectedImageCompressed: UIImage?

func tappedPhoto(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView)) {

        let imageView = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        startingFrame = imageView?.superview?.convert((imageView?.frame)!, to: nil)

        let zoomingImageView = UIImageView(frame: startingFrame!)
        zoomingImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row - 1]
        zoomingImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        zoomingImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        zoomingImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomOut)))

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackBackGroundView = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            blackBackGroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            blackBackGroundView?.alpha = 0

            keyWindow.addSubview(blackBackGroundView!)
            keyWindow.addSubview(chooseLabel)
            keyWindow.addSubview(zoomingImageView)

            // Set selected image and compress
            selectedImageFromPicker = imageArray[indexPath.row - 1]
            selectedImageCompressed = selectedImageFromPicker?.resized(withPercentage: 0.1)

            chooseLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyWindow.rightAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
            chooseLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyWindow.bottomAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.blackBackGroundView?.alpha = 1
                self.chooseLabel.alpha = 1

                let height = self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width * keyWindow.frame.width

                zoomingImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)

                zoomingImageView.center = keyWindow.center

                }, completion: {(completed) in
                    // Do nothing
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your selected cell function?

Comment: Check updated ans.

Comment: Added the selected cell function :-)

Comment: Added the answer to my question. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to add two sections, or should I register another custom
>   cell to accomplish this?

In your case, just adding one cell at the beginning of the collection should be fair enough, there is no need to multi-section it.

Your methods should be implemented as follows:

**1-** `numberOfItemsInSection` method: should be as is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count + 1
}
```

**2-** `cellForItemAt` method: depends on the first cell, if it should be a different cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // first row
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cameraCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cameraCell-ID", for: indexPath)

        // setup the cell...

        return cameraCell
    }

    let defaultCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "defaultCell-ID", for: indexPath)

    // setup default cell...

    return defaultCell
}
```

Or, if you want it to be the same cell, but with some editions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell-ID", for: indexPath)

    // first row
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // setup the cell as cemera cell...
    } else {
        // setup the cell as default cell...
    }

    return cell
}
```

Actually, there is no need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each cell, all you have to do is to implement [collection​View(_:​did​Select​Item​At:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) delegate method:

> Tells the delegate that the item at the specified index path was
>   selected.

**3-** `didSelectItemAt` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 { // camera cell
        // handle tapping the camera cell
    } else { // default cells
        // handle tapping the default cell

        // don't forget that:
        // getting the first element in 'imageArray' should be imageArray[indexPath.row - 1]
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot. The reason why I did not use `didSelectItemAt Index` is because I have embedded my collectionView inside a UIView. To handle zooming in and out, I used a tapGesture to get the location of the image and create another view on top of everything else. I still can't get it to work though :-(

Comment: I fixed it! Your explanation helped me achieve this, so I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Glad to help :)